# What is the real audio sample rate in AVCaptureSession for 6s model?

Tags: ios, audio

I set the audio sample rate to 44.1k.

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                       error:nil];

[audioSession setPreferredSampleRate:44100.0f error:nil];
[audioSession setPreferredOutputNumberOfChannels:1 error:nil];
//[audioSession setPreferredInputNumberOfChannels:2 error:nil];
[audioSession setPreferredIOBufferDuration:(1024.0f / 44100.0f) error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
NSLog(@"Audio session sampleRate = %f, outputNumberOfChannels = %d, duration = %f.", audioSession.sampleRate, audioSession.outputNumberOfChannels, audioSession.IOBufferDuration);
```

This print 48000 for 6s/6s plus model, 44100 for other models.
in the AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription inputFormat = *(CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)));
```

**Note:** but the samplerate always 44100 reference to inputformat, and the sample size is 1880, 1882, 2048.

What is the real sample rate? 44100 or 48000?

Comment: The 6S family are 48000

Comment: But inputFormat.mSampleRate print 44100. Take case the size of samplebuffer is 1880,  1880/2=940 samples, if 44100 then duration = 940 * 1000 / 44100 = 21.32ms, if 48000 then duration = 940 * 1000 / 48000 = 19.58ms。 The real duration of 1880 size samplebuffer is 21.32ms, I calculate this by the pts of this samplebuffer minus the pts of the previous  samplebuffer.